# error in unity 3d loading script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

when i m loading a script in unity i m facing given below i m a new learner kindly tell me how to fix it .

MissingFieldException: UnityEngine.Transform.Position
Boo.Lang.Runtime.DynamicDispatching.PropertyDispatcherFactory.FindExtension (IEnumerable`1 candidates)
Boo.Lang.Runtime.DynamicDispatching.PropertyDispatcherFactory.Create (SetOrGet gos)
Boo.Lang.Runtime.DynamicDispatching.PropertyDispatcherFactory.CreateSetter ()
Boo.Lang.Runtime.RuntimeServices.DoCreatePropSetDispatcher (System.Object target, System.Type type, System.String name, System.Object value)
Boo.Lang.Runtime.RuntimeServices.CreatePropSetDispatcher (System.Object target, System.String name, System.Object value)
Boo.Lang.Runtime.RuntimeServices+c__AnonStorey19.<>m__F ()
Boo.Lang.Runtime.DynamicDispatching.DispatcherCache.Get (Boo.Lang.Runtime.DynamicDispatching.DispatcherKey key, Boo.Lang.Runtime.DynamicDispatching.DispatcherFactory factory)
Boo.Lang.Runtime.RuntimeServices.GetDispatcher (System.Object target, System.String cacheKeyName, System.Type[] cacheKeyTypes, Boo.Lang.Runtime.DynamicDispatching.DispatcherFactory factory)
Boo.Lang.Runtime.RuntimeServices.GetDispatcher (System.Object target, System.Object[] args, System.String cacheKeyName, Boo.Lang.Runtime.DynamicDispatching.DispatcherFactory factory)
Boo.Lang.Runtime.RuntimeServices.SetProperty (System.Object target, System.String name, System.Object value)
pick up.OnMouseDown () (at Assets/scripts/pick up.js:8)
UnityEngine.SendMouseEvents:DoSendMouseEvents(Int32)

Comment: Can you post the part of the script that is producing the error?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please go through the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) and the [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Answer (score 0):

Position should be written with a lowercase "p". 
Classes are generally written with a capital first (eg. Transform, Vector3, GameObject). Classes hold the definitions of objects, but no values.

Class instances like "transform.position" are generally with a lowercase first letter. They hold the real values of objects. This is where you change positions, rotate objects, change materials, etc.

My guess: In your "pick up.js", see if you try to call the instance "Transform.Position" and rename it to "transform.position".